# qobject_cast<QVBoxLayout*>(layout()), is the appropriate cast?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt4, qt5

Considering the layout was set in a `QWidget` with the following code:

```
setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
```

And then it needs to be retrieved (to add more stuff to the layout). This was done with the following code:

```
QHBoxLayout *hLayoutTime(new QHBoxLayout);
qobject_cast<QVBoxLayout*>(layout())->addLayout(hLayoutTime);
```

`qobject_cast` is the appropriate kind of cast to use here?

Comment: it is ok, in fact static_cast would be better here. On other hand you are creating unneeded problems. Just use local variables to build you layout structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid unneded casting write this like this:

```
void YourWidget::setupContents()
{
     QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this); // effectively this does setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);

     QHBoxLayout *hLayoutTime(new QHBoxLayout);
     vLayout->addLayout(hLayoutTime);
     … … …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking the code in your current example, Why don't you just get the pointer when creating?

```
auto *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
auto *hLayoutTime = new QHBoxLayout;
vLayout->addlaout(hLayoutTime);
```

Answering your question, probably the most adequate cast is:

```
dynamic_cast<QHBoxLayout*>(new QVBoxLayout);
```

dynamic_cast has several checks and benefits over static_cast, so it is better to use it when possible.

Comment: I'm wondering if @Marek R agree with you in respect of `dynamic_cast `.

Comment: @KcFnMi Good question ;-)

Comment: `qobject_cast` is equivalent of `dynamic_cast` but is Qt specific. I read somewhere that `dynamic_cast` experience  some problems with libraries and `qobject_cast` doesn't have this problem (I didn't stored the link I will try to find it).

Comment: documentation also mentions something: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast bottom line in Qt code for `QObjects` use `qobject_cast` if needed.

Comment: Of course Qt will always push for Qt technologies, but my experience is: keep Qt as little as possible and you will avoid troubles: Their full library has lot of very bad designs decisions which make difficult to integrate QT with others (e.g. their buggy memory deallocation). Using a custom cast function/macro is IMO also a risky bet.

Comment: That "lot of very bad designs decisions" is listed somewhere?

Comment: @KcFnMi: I did not searched for it, that is why this was a comment and not in the answer. Some of them: 1) use of non-standard C++, which make mandatory moc, and thus make impossible to use modern C++ with QT (try new function syntax, etc..) 2) Private class (anti?) pattern: to make DLL compatibility, they hide all the implementation of the class, making impossible to extend the library. So instead of spending 2h every 6 month in rebuilding my project, I spent 3 month to create Qt from basic QWidgets. 3) keywords like virtual are missing, so again, very difficult to extend/improve. etc..

Comment: 4) Garbage collection, which go against C++ principles, and some times (in a non coherent way) even stole ownership, so creating an object on the stack make the application to crash. 5) Incoherent function design: some times you have "get/set", others not (hidden/visible), rect vs geometry, setPos vs setTopLeft, ....

Comment: Well, and is there something better then Qt available? What should I look for instead?